# div won't move to left or respond to positioning

Tags: html, css, position

I'm new to coding so this is a simple page for a course (full code below includes html and inline css).

The problem is that my  is not responding to positioning -- and it wouldn't respond to "float:left;" prior to using the positioning code.  I loaded the page in firefox, chrome, and several online code test sites (e.g. codepen, squarefree).
Thank you for your help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning CSS</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

   <style type="text/css">

        .large {
            font-size:200%;
        }

        #green {
            color:green;
        }

        .underline {
            text-decoration:underline;
        }

        .bold {
            font-weight:bold;
        }

        .purplebox {
            background-color:#8904B1; 
            width:200px;
            height:200px
            position:relative;
            left:100px; 
        }

        .greenbox {
            background-color:#01DF01;
            width:300px;
            height:100px;
        }


    </style>    

</head>

<body>

    <div class="purplebox">

        <p class="large">This is some text.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="greenbox">

        <p id="green" class="large">This is some more text.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p>The third <span class="underline large bold">word</span> in this paragraph is underlined.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which box are we talking about?

Comment: That was it Jhecht -- thank you! Without the semicolon the div wouldn't respond to positioning.  I missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but I think your biggest problem is that you didn't put a semicolon before your `position` in your `.purplebox` element's CSS.

Your Original CSS:

```
.purplebox {
            background-color:#8904B1; 
            width:200px;
            height:200px /*No semicolon*/
            position:relative;
            left:100px; 
        }
```

Fixed CSS, which appears to work for me in the Stackoverflow Snippet editor.

```
.purplebox {
      background-color: #8904B1;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px; /* Semicolon */
      position: relative;
      left: 100px;
    }
```

```css
.large {
  font-size: 200%;
}
#green {
  color: green;
}
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.purplebox {
  background-color: #8904B1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}
.greenbox {
  background-color: #01DF01;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="purplebox">

  <p class="large">This is some text.</p>

</div>

<div class="greenbox">

  <p id="green" class="large">This is some more text.</p>

</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<p>The third <span class="underline large bold">word</span> in this paragraph is underlined.</p>
```